# In heatmap apexcharts how can we remove duplicate x axis labels?

Tags: apexcharts

How can I remove the duplicates from x axis labels in heatmap apexcharts
Here the JSFiddle Link
[click here](https://jsfiddle.net/athisandy/pbvedkty/24/)

[image]

Here multiple May months are showing I need to display only one in the Middle of 4 columns.
I tried the below

```
xaxis: {
           labels: {showDuplicates: false}
         }
```

But this is not working as expected.

Comment: I suspect that the showDuplicates options is only for [datetime series](https://apexcharts.com/docs/datetime/) axis (from the [docs](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/xaxis/#showDuplicates):"prevent congested values in datetime series"). An alternative approach to prevent duplicates with a heatmap might be to remove any duplicates before passing the series to ApexCharts.

Answer (score 5):

We need to add the x axis like below and change the x axis value to a date

```
xaxis: {
                type: "datetime",
                labels: {
                format: 'MMM',
                showDuplicates: false}
              }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/athisandy/fuyb3vjh/13/)

Comment: These charts are keep getting better and better.